# c# Capturing and taking a screenshot of a window in a infinite loop

Tags: c#, screenshot, emgucv

I make screenshot of a window in a infinite loop
it works good.
But I hope it can be improved.
When i run my project, it has a litter delay to copy "Myscreen" from "PictureBox".

Anyone have a idea?
Or did you know any other solutions?

I just want to get Screen's BITMAP constantly.(faster..)

Below source is screen capture function.

```
public static Bitmap ScreenCapture_B(System.Windows.Forms.Screen MyScreen)
    {

        try
        {
            Rectangle rect = MyScreen.Bounds;
            // 2nd screen = Screen.AllScreens[1]
            int bitsPerPixel = MyScreen.BitsPerPixel;
            PixelFormat pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
            if (bitsPerPixel <= 16)
            {
                pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565;
            }
            if (bitsPerPixel == 24)
            {
                pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
            }
            else
            {
                pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
            }
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, pixelFormat);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                // 화면을 그대로 카피해서 Bitmap 메모리에 저장
                gr.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, rect.Size);
            }
            return bmp;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Bellow source is Thread.

```
public void ThreadLoop()
    {
        try
        {
            //infinite loop
            while (true)
            {
                bm = null;
                Screen MyScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
                bm = ScreenCapture_B(MyScreen);
                setImage(bm, pictureEdit1);                    
                Bitmap btimage = new Bitmap(pictureEdit1.Image);
                ProcessImage_new(btimage);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you use a Try/Catch only to rethrow the exception? Also, there is a chance that the Try/Catch slows down your code.

Comment: If bitmap supports multiple writes you can avoid to instantiate a new bitmap  every time, moreover you should dispose the bitmap after you use it to help with memory consumption and with new allocations (it affects speed)